# Inequality involved in Slutsky's Proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Why is the following inequality true?
$$P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)\leq P(\{X_n+Y_n\leq x\} \ \cap \{|Y_n-c|<\epsilon\})+P(|Y_n-c|\geq\epsilon)$$
I've been trying to think of it as:
$$P(A)\leq P(A\cap B)+P(B^c)$$
But there is a step in this conclusion I'm not seeing.

edit for the proof, but is there a shorter way to do this that is slightly easier to see?

Proof:
$$P(A^c \cup B^c)\leq P(A^c)+P(B^c)\Rightarrow -P(A^c\cup B^c)\geq-P(A^c)-P(B^c)$$
$$\Rightarrow 1-P(A^c\cup B^c)\geq1-P(A^c)-P(B^c)$$
Thus
$$P(A\cap B)=1-P((A\cap B)^c)=1-P(A^c\cup B^c)\geq 1-P(A^c)-P(B^c)$$
$$=1-(1-P(A))-P(B^c)=P(A)-P(B^c)$$
$$\Rightarrow P(A\cap B)\geq P(A)-P(B^c)$$
$$\Rightarrow P(A\cap B)+P(B^c) \geq P(A). \ \ \square$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)= P(\{X_n+Y_n\leq x\} \ \cap \{|Y_n-c|<\epsilon\})+P(\{X_n+Y_n\leq x\}\cap \{|Y_n-c|\geq\epsilon\})
$$
by the law of total probability but 
$$
P(\{X_n+Y_n\leq x\}\cap \{|Y_n-c|\geq\epsilon\})\leq P(|Y_n-c|\geq\epsilon)
$$
since one event is a subset of the other. The result follows.

Comment: Thank you!  That is MUCH clearer to see than what I was trying to make sense of.

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of the following fact:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)+\mathbb{P}(A\cap B^c)
\leq \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)+\mathbb{P}(B^c)
$$
*(the first equality is the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), and the inequality follows from $A\cap B^c \subseteq B^c$)*
applied to $A = \{X_n+Y_n \leq x\}$ and $B=\{\lvert Y_n-c\rvert < \varepsilon\}$.